# What does this orange icon mean in eclipse mars?

Tags: eclipse, icons, orange

[image: icons]

I have checked: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm?resultof=%22%69%63%6f%6e%22%20

to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea of what this could mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those folders (or files) are being managed by a source control system such as Git or SVN.

Comment: Thanks greg, Do you know how to add these to my classpath? or any links to documention related to this?

Comment: @dev That is a completely different question. Accept this answer (click the tick mark next to the answer) and ask a new question - but please take the [tour] and learn how to [ask].